# compile error named argument not found

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Excel workbook that contains several sheets in the same fields.
I want to layout from a model sheet.
In order to find the code, I create a macro. When I run it in Excel it works. I'm transposing the code in Access and I get the error message:

> Compile error named argument not found

Here is the detail of the code (Button) In the part in error.

```
Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
```

This gives you a value of 8, so replace `xlPasteColumnWidths` with the number `8`.

```
Private Sub Commande92_Click()

Dim vStatusBar As String
    Application.SetOption "Show Status Bar", True

   vStatusBar = SysCmd(acSysCmdSetStatus, "Mise en page des feuilles EXCEL ... veuillez patienter.")

 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
 Dim xlSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim sSheet As String, Rep1 As String, LaDate As String, MoisDate As String, StTarget As String, Sql1 As String
 Dim thedb As DAO.Recordset

LaDate = Now()
MoisDate = Format(LaDate, "ddmm")

Rep1 = "F:\PELO\PELO 2018-2019\FichiersInscriptionParent\"
Sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT tblEcole.Abvr, tblEcole.NomEcole FROM tblEcole;"

StTarget = Rep1 & "EcolePELO" & "_" & MoisDate & ".xlsm"


Set xlBook = GetObject(StTarget)
'filename is the string with the link to the file ("C:/....blahblah.xls")

Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If xlApp Is Nothing Then
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

'Make sure excel is visible on the screen
xlApp.Visible = True
xlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

'xl.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75

 sSheet = thedb(0)

'Define the sheet in the Workbook as XlSheet1
Set xlSheet1 = xlBook.Worksheets(1)



    With xlSheet1
     '.Name = "Modele"
      .Select "Modele"
      .Rows("1:2").Select
      .Copy
      .Name = sSheet
      .Select sSheet
      .Rows("1:1").Select
      ''''
      ' Bloc ici
      ''''
      .PasteSpecial **Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths**, Operation:=xlNone, _
       SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
      .Range("B3").Select
      .Application.CutCopyMode = False
      .Selection.Copy
      .Range("B1:N1").Select
      .ActiveSheet.Paste
      .Range("A3:B266").Select
      .Application.CutCopyMode = False
      .App

    End With

       xlSheet1.aActiveSheet.Sheet (1)
      ' xlApp.ActiveSheet.Name = "Modele"
       xlSheet1.Sheets("Modele").Select
       xlSheet1.Application.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete , True
       xlBook.Save , True
       xlBook.Close
       xlApp.Quit



Err_MCommande92_Click:
    vStatusBar = SysCmd(acSysCmdClearStatus)
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Commande92_Click


Exit_Commande92_Click:
vStatusBar = SysCmd(acSysCmdClearStatus)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: On the line with Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths

Comment: Access should understand `xlPasteColumnWidths` and `xlNone` as you're using early binding - you're using `Dim xlApp As Excel.Application`.  **But**, saying that, you also use `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` which is the late binding method.  Have you set a reference to Excel from Access?

Comment: After looking through your code I haven't got a clue what you're trying to do.  From what I can work out:  Open the file in `Rep1` path with name of `EcolePELO` and todays date.  Copy rows 1:2 of the first sheet in tab order (name of sheet doesn't matter).  Rename the sheet to the `dao.recordset` which hasn't been opened yet? Paste the column widths into row 1 even though you copied them from rows 1:2 so they won't have changed.  Copy cell B3 and paste to cell B1:N1?  And finally delete the sheet?

Comment: OK,  I have a workbook that contant multiples sheets with the same row. I want to make the same format page with a model that i include yo the workbook. I use the code form a Excel MAro that i record from the wotkbook. So i put the code into Access because i use access to export dato to the spreadsheet method.  Is that clear ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enumeration is only defined in Excel. To look up the value of an Enumeration, use google. `Enum xlPasteColumnWidths` gives you these results:

[Enum xlPasteColumnWidths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpastetype-enumeration-excel)

so replace `xlPasteColumnWidths` with the value of `8`

Comment: Do you really use Google to lookup enumeration?

Comment: OK, I put some Enum like tis and get error message again

Comment: See how to avoid google here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48765020/5448626

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the following:

```
With xlSheet1

      .Select "Modele"
      .Rows("1:2").Select
      .Copy
      .Name = sSheet
      .Select sSheet
      .Rows("1:1").Select
      ''''
      ' Bloc ici
      ''''
      .PasteSpecial **Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths**, Operation:=xlNone, _
       SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

The `With` means that everything after the point goes to with the with. Thus, you are getting something like `xlSheet1.PasteSpecial ...`, which is a bit illegal, because you have only the first 2 rows copied.

Long story short, try like this:

```
.Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=8, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

It should probably work. If it does, find a way to avoid the `Select` and `ActiveSheet` in your code.